# Redhat Serva PXE boot doesn't load menu from ISO file

Tags: system-installation, pxe

I have RedHat installation DVD where I have simple menu which one I can see if I boot from DVD (for kickstart purposes). I'm trying to get to this menu using Serva PXE Server. Client boots from network then I select "REDHAT" but installation process looks like a standard RedHat installation. I would like to see my menu before normal installation starts. All files from ISO were unpacked coorectly to Serva directory, I have isolinux\isolinux.cfg, isolinux\menus directory and so on.

My `ServaAsset.inf` file:

```
[PXESERVA_MENU_ENTRY]
asset    = REDHAT
platform = x86_64
kernel_bios    = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/isolinux/vmlinuz
append_bios    = initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/isolinux/initrd.img splash=silent vga=0x314 showopts netdevice=bootif -c /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/isolinux/isolinux.cfg inst.repo=http://$IP_BSRV$:8000/$HEAD_DIR$/
ipappend_bios   = 2
kernel_efi64   = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/isolinux/vmlinuz
append_efi64   = initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/isolinux/initrd.img splash=silent vga=0x314 showopts netdevice=bootif -c /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/isolinux/isolinux.cfg inst.repo=http://$IP_BSRV$:8000/$HEAD_DIR$/
```

I tried to modify kernel_bios option but without success. Does Serva Community edition has any directive for `isolinux.cfg` or `vesamenu.c32` files?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Serva BINL mode then you can just copy your `ServaAsset.inf` from:

https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html.

You don't have to add anything else. It works perfectly with both Serva "Community" and "Pro"